# Adobe Sign with Salesforce - Set redirect URL after sending for Signature

Tags: redirect, salesforce, visualforce, sign, echosign

I am working on integrating Adobe sign with Salesforce for digital signatures.

I am using the send URL (below format) to send the document for signing.

```
https://echosign-dev1.ap1.visual.force.com/apex/EchoSignAgreementAdvanced?id=[agreementID]&sfdc.override=1&onLoadAction=send
```

This redirect me to the visualforce page like below, and by clicking the "Send for Signature" button, I can send this doc to the recipient to sign.

[image]

My question is how to redirect back to a Salesforce record page once the document sent. What happen now is it redirect back to the same page as on above screenshot. I need to set a custom redirect URL. Appreciate your help.

Note : In Adobe doc, there is a way to redirect once the recipient signed the doc. but not my requrement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer to this question.

We can assign the return URL to the below custom field of the Agreement object

```
echosign_dev1__ReturnURL__c
```